# How can i start the GDB server in stm32cubeide?

Tags: gdb, stm32ldiscovery, stm32cubeide

right now I am trying to program on the STM32G0-Disco-board with the program stm32cubeide on WIN10.
This worked fine until it didn't.
My problem right now is that I can't debug/run it anymore. This is the first day I used this program, which doesn't mean it didn't worked at the beginning. Building, Debugging and Running worked just fine.
But now I get this error message:

```
Error in final launch sequence:

Failed to start GDB server
Failed to start GDB server
Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: (4) No device found on target.
```

I already tried multiple usb-ports, the jumper on the board. I even looked in this Batchfile:
C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.3.0\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.stlink-gdb-server.win32_1.3.0.202002181050\tools\bin
ST_LINK_gdbserver because it was mentioned in other threads and i just got this:

ERROR: Couldn't locate STM32CubeProgrammer in '..\STM32CubeProgrammer\bin\', use -cp 
GDB server exited.
And oh yeah i already looked into the device manager and everything looks good to me.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Now a serious comment: Please try disconnecting and reconnecting your ST-Link adapter, and to power-cycle your target (unless both happens at the same time as in the default configuration). You may also have to reboot the PC in rare cases, but I don't believe the reason is some batch file, especially not when it used to work.

Comment: I honestly couldn't get it to work. So i just bought a 2nd Discovery-Kit. Anyway thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and i managed to solve it . It turns out that my antivirus software (avast) was preventing the debugger from starting by removing the file ST_LINK_gdb.exe from its place and putting it in the antivirus chest.[image]

The solution was to open the virus chest and and restore the file and also add an exception. And this solved the problem.[image]

Comment: Thanks. It was my anti-virus software that was preventing gdb server execution.

Answer (score 0):

Short BOOT0 (see the pinout of your board) to the 3.3 V, then power cycle, and program it

Comment: I get the same error as before. Is there any change that my virusprogramm deleted something?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, thank you Chris for your suggestions!

To be clear, these are the steps I followed:

1. short BOOT0 to +3.3V (BOOT0 and 1 are pulled low via 1K on my board)
2. cycle power *with the short in place*
3. remove the short
4. cycle power again
5. good to go!